# Create one php variable from several

Tags: php

Basic question but I've searched and can't quite get this nailed - how can I create 1 variable from several others? I then want to get that into an array.

Something like this (obviously the syntax is wrong!):

```
$name;
$address;
$post_code;

$full_address = $name, $address, $post_code;
$address[] = $full_address;
```

My php is very basic so go easy on the abuse!

Comment: `$address = array( $name, $address, $post_code ); `

Comment: You can concatenate, like you've basically done, or you can add each to an array. Can you explain a bit more about what you actually want to get/see at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this basic or how you want it to be done:

```
$separator = " ";
$full_address = "{$name}{$separator}{$address}{$separator}{$postcode}";
$address[] = $full_address;
```

Comment: Why not just `implode($separator,array($name,$address,$postcode))` in this situation?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it several ways:

```
// using sprintf
$address[] = sprintf('%s, %s, %s', $name, $address, $post_code);

// using "Traditional" concatenation
$address[] = "$name, $address, $post_code";

// other version of concatenation
$address[] = $name . ", " . $address . ", " . $post_code;
```

Or if you want them as an array:

```
// regular array
$address[] = array($name, $address, $post_code);
// $address[n][0] = name
// $address[n][1] = address
// $address[n][2] = post_code

// keyed array
$address[] = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'address' => $address,
  'post_code' => $post_code
);
// $address[n]['name'] = name
// $address[n]['address'] = address
// $address[n]['post_code'] = post_code
```

Answer (score 4):

Since noone else mentioned it, [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact)

```
$name = 'Mike';
$address = '123 Main St';
$post_code = '55555';

$full_address = compact('name', 'address', 'post_code');
var_dump($full_address);

/* Output:
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "Mike"
  ["address"]=>
  string(11) "123 Main St"
  ["post_code"]=>
  string(5) "55555"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you simply wanting to append several strings to each other?

If so the correct syntax is this:

```
$name = 'Dave Random';
$address = 'Some place, some other place';
$post_code = 'AB123CD';

$merged = $name.$address.$post_code;
```

...using `.` (dot) to [concatentate](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=concatenate) them. You will probably want to insert a line break, comma etc between them:

```
$merged = $name.', '.$address.', '.$post_code;
```

Alternatively, you can specify them all in one new string like this:

```
$merged = "$name, $address, $post_code";
```

...note the use of doubles quotes instead of single. It would probably do you well to [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Alternatively, you can store them as separate values in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) like this:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray['name'] = 'Dave Random';
$myArray['address'] = 'Some place, some other place';
$myArray['post_code'] = 'AB123CD';
```

...or this:

```
$myArray = array(
  'name' => 'Dave Random',
  'address' => 'Some place, some other place',
  'post_code' => 'AB123CD'
);
```

...and your can convert that array to a string with [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$merged = implode(', ',$myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple array:

```
$full_address = array($name, $address, $post_code);
```

For an associative array:

```
$full_address = array('name'=>$name, 'address'=>$address, 'zip'=>$post_code);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to concatenate strings? You should use string concatenation operator "**.**".
For example:

```
$s1 = "foo";
$s2 = "bar";
$s3 = "blabla";
$final_string = $s1 . " " . $s2 . $s3;
echo $final_string; // output: "foo barblabla"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called **string concatenation** and this is done in PHP with the `.`-Operator

```
$name = "Foo";
$address = "Barstreet 1";
$post_code = "12345 Foobar";

$full_address = $name . ", " . $address . ", " . $post_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much almost there.

```
$name = 'Your name';
$address = 'Your address';
$post_code = 'Your post code';

$full_address = "$name, $address, $post_code";
$address[] = $full_address;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to concatenate name adress and postcode you can do:

```
$address[] = $name.$address.$post_code;
or 
$address[] = "$name $address $post_code";
```

if what you want is to add each of the field to the adress array you can do this as :

```
$address = array($name,$address,$post_code);
or 
$address[] = $name;
$address[] = $address;
$address[] = $post_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at standard object:

```
$address = new stdClass;
$address->postcode = '02115';
$address->name = "John Connor';
```

or create an Address class by itself, it will be quite useful in your app.

```
class Address {

     public function __construct ($name, $address) {...}
     public function getFullAddress() {...} // or other useful functions
}
```